# Customised Scrollable Team Strip in Wix

Tags: velo

I want to create a team strip with 12 people in it but when I look forward to using available team strip - I can't able to set up these many people through horizontal scrolling.

At present not scrolling option is available so maximum within the screen you can file 5 to 6 persons maximum.
Here is the example where only 5 people possible to add:
[image]

But I want a scrollable team strip - how to customize this?

If any other way exists then let me know, I want to show 12 persons within the single list with their details as in the template.

Answer (score 0):

for this instance if you'd like 12 spaces for each team member I would suggest that you use a repeater and a dataset instead of a strip. If you'd like the horizontal sliding effect use a slider gallery instead of a repeater. This will require you to use Corvid.

1. Enable Corvid by turning on Dev Mode. It's on the top of the editor
   right next to tools and help.
2. Create a database collection by hovering over Database and click the
   plus button and follow the menu. After, add entries to your
   database. You can store your team member's pictures, bio etc...
   Whatever you'd like.
3. Now that you have a collection, Add a repeater or gallery slider to
   the page you'll find it in the List & Grids or Galleries section in
   the UI menu.
4. Go to the content manager on the left side of the editor and click
   add content elements. Next click Connect a collection to create a
   dataset.
5. You'll see a little square pop up on the editor, that is the
   dataset. Click settings and choose the collection you'd like to
   connect it to. You'll see in the settings menu you have the ability
   to change the number of items on display. The default is 12 and you
   can change it to whatever number you desire. You also have filter
   options.

When you preview your page you'll see your content load.

follow these video tutorials:
[Corvid by Wix | How to Use a Gallery or Repeater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBkF-eGI38o&list=PL0y_aclKYoYhzHA9TbgEhzU68bvRI15mI&index=10)

[Corvid by Wix How to set up a database collection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NcL72uzy1ZU&list=PL0y_aclKYoYhzHA9TbgEhzU68bvRI15mI&index=17)